# How do I input php variables in html mail

Tags: php, html, webforms

Hi there I'm trying to send an HTML email through a PHP webform. The form works fine and if I pass the variables such as $name, $address in to the message it goes through ok, but when I try to format it using HTML I can't seem to get those variables passed into the message. This is an example code I found on w3schools but I can't seem to adjust it to do what I want:

```
<?php
....
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";
 ....
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is pass the variable $name where it says "john doe", and I guess once I figure that out I should be able to pass through all my other variables as well.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by not being able to pass variables? If you put $name inbetween the `<td>` tags, what gets sent?

Comment: Please make sure you're sanitizing data collected from the form. If you don't, you're opening yourself up to possible code injection attacks.

Comment: Your email is very badly formed - the HTML part MUST have a mime type, disposition and encoding along with delimiters. While some MUAs will still render it, you might want to get hold of something like phpmailer which does it properly.

Comment: @symcbean: or just use PHPMailer/Swiftmailer to do all that for you, rather than trying to build the mime envelope manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your variables into the message, if you are using double quotes, you should just be able to include the variable in the string:

eg

```
$message = "
<html>
...
<tr>
<td>$name</td>
</tr>
...
</html>
";
```

You can also break out of the string

```
$message = "
<html>
...
<tr>
<td>".$name."</td>
</tr>
...
</html>
";
```

Which will work with single or double quotes (personally I prefer this method with single quotes).

However when you receive this email, you will see the raw html.  In order to have the html displayed properly you will need to set the appropriate mail headers.  There are examples of how to do this [here](http://css-tricks.com/2866-sending-nice-html-email-with-php/) and [here](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php)

Comment: Or just use a HEREDOC, which gets completely around the need to escape internal quotes. There's no reason to close the string and concatenate either. Any marginally decent editor with syntax highlighting will see the internal variables and highlight them.

Comment: A heredoc would also do the job.  The reason I prefer to use single quotes and close the strings is because I don't like the way that PHP automatically parses double-quoted strings for variables etc, most of the time unnecessarily.  All the best practice guides I've read advise against the use of double quotes in php unless specifically required for performance reasons (not that I really think it makes that much difference - am more just used to it that way now!)

Comment: If you're not using variables, then there's NOWDOC (http://php.net/nowdoc), which is the single-quote equivalent of a heredoc's double-quotes.

Comment: I tried passing in the $name without closing and concatenating but it didnt work. So when I did do it using the second method it worked fine! Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1):

```
$message = "
  <html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>".$firstname."</td>
<td>".$lastname."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should split the name into two idivdual variables e.g. `$first_name` and `$second_name`. This is possible to by doing this:

```
<?php

$split_names = explode(' ', $name); // assuming you have a space between both

$first_name = $split_names[0];
$last_name = $split_names[1];

?>
```

Then you can do this:

```
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>" . $first_name . "</td>
<td>" . $second_name . "</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";
 ....
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply like this:

```
$message = "
<html>
...
<tr>
<td>".htmlspecialchars($name)."</td>
</tr>
...
</html>
";
```

It's **very import** to escape content that isn't controlled by you (i.e. collected from a form) to prevent injection attacks. In this case, we use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).